# How to merge objects from two different arrays of same length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I am working in vanilla JavaScript.
I have two arrays of the same length.
Each of them is containing objects.
I need to create one array with objects combined.
How?

So, in code, my input is:

```
const arr1 = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Peter"}];
const arr2 = [{age: 56}, {age: 22}]
```

Desirable output:

```
const arr3 = [{name: "John", age: 56}, {name: "Peter", age: 22}]
```

I saw solution that ES6 offers, and it goes like this:

```
const object1 = {
  name: 'John'
}
const object2 = {
  age: 56
}
const object3 = {...object1, ...object2 }
```

That works just great! I would like to implement this same solution in this example whit objects in arrays using this spread operator. How? :)

Thank you.

Comment: With a bit more effort in a loop i bet you could have gotten this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and spread syntax:

```js
const arr1 = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Peter' }];
const arr2 = [{ age: 56 }, { age: 22 }];
const arr3 = arr1.map((v, i) => ({ ...v, ...arr2[i] }));
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```js
const arr1 = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Peter"}];
const arr2 = [{age: 56}, {age: 22}];
const result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) result.push(Object.assign(arr1[i], arr2[i]));

console.log(result)
```

P.S, also as @charlietfl mentioned: if you don't want to mutate objects in `arr1` start with empty object ... `Object.assign({},arr1[i], arr2[i])`

Comment: And if you don't want to mutate objects in arr1 start with empty object ... `Object.assign({},arr1[i], arr2[i])`